# Crack in ABS drain pipe at slab

Tags: leak, drain, crack, slab, abs

As pictured, this is my kitchen drain line and vent.  It may be hard to see in the photos, but the 2" ABS goes into the concrete slab. Due to earth movement (my guess, and you can see the line isn't straight), the pipe is cracked right at the point entering the slab!  This was causing drain leak into my patio luckily and not inside.

I opened it up and clearly see the crack, which hard to see in the photo, but marked in red.  The green circle show the location of the clean-out on the other side of the wall in the patio.

So given the crack is at the same level of the top of the slab, I can't easily patch is up with a new section.  This is where I need you brains :)

couple ideas came to me:

1. Put a 1.5" ABS piece inside the 2" sealed with ABS cement.
2. just use ABS cement to patch the crack from inside and outside, and then use flex rubber coupling to connect the rest (to release stress on the repaired part).

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Drain pipes are low pressure, so ABS cement on the clean inside surface of the pipe might work, depending on the size of the crack.  A thin piece of ABS cemented over the crack would be better, but cleaning of the pipe is the most important.  This will require removing and replacing most of those joints to get at that section of pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Concrete can be removed and replaced. It's not forever and untouchable.

That's the correct way to fix this. Chisel out until you get enough clear, un-cracked pipe to put a coupling on. After completing the repair, wrap the pipe with a thin layer of closed cell foam (they sell large rolls of it as "foam closet wrap" but you may be able to repurpose some packing foam) to buffer the pipe from the concrete you pour around it (had that been done the first time, you might not be facing this repair now.)

Comment: It's a violation of the plumbing codes I'm familiar with to embed any kind of pipe directly in concrete. Here we see why. Pipes are supposed to be sleeved and/or  surrounded with elastomeric sealing material to prevent such damage.